# What does if ( a & 1) means where a is an int?

Tags: c++, boolean, logic, bit-manipulation

Given this code

```
int arry[2]; //equal to some values

if (arry[0] & 1) //what does this mean?
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It is using the bitwise `AND` operator to test if the `int`'s lowest bit is 1.

Comment: To add to @RemyLebeau, this checks if a number is odd.

Comment: Yeah that is makes sense lowest bit being one means odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. Bitwise AND operation performs the logical AND operation for the corresponding bits of each operand. In the case of `a & 1`, the left hand operand is the integer `a`, and the right hand operand is the integer `1`.

`if` keyword is syntax for the if-statement. The simplified grammar of the statement is:

```
if ( condition ) statement-true
```

The `statement-true` statement is executed only if the `condition` expression is true. Here, the type of the `condition` expression is an integer type. In this case, the condition is true if the value of the result of the bitwise operation is not zero.

Comment: A & 1 is “true” if A’s 1 bit is on.